# React: Universal method to handle input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for smart method to handle input change in React

I have input

```
<input type="text" name="name" onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e)} />
```

And function to handle input change

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
```

But I need to change sometimes not property of state, but property of state object (or property of property of state object...) for example:

```
const entity = this.state.entity;
entity[name] = value;
this.setState({
   entity: entity
)}
```

Some ideas for multilevel?

Comment: for multi-level, you can use dot notation, `name="location.lat"` for example, and write some code to iterate through the levels of the .notation or use a library

Comment: a library like this would do it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, you might do something like this:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    
    this.setState(prevState => {
        const newState = Object.assign({}, prevState  );
        // https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path
        ObjectPath.set(state, name, value);
        return state;
    });
}
```

using this library.

That way, when your input name is `"a.b.c"`, it will go to the nested object `state.a.b` and change the `c` property